# Beginner php.ini and .htaccess

Tags: php, vps

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
```

I use this code in .htaccess to shorten url on my old shared hosting server.How I write this to use in php.ini on new vps server?
I'm begineer.I use CWP on my vps.
Please answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not put this to `php.ini`! It's about Apache web server, not about PHP.

Create `.htaccess` file in your website root and put your rules into it.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) you can find a manual for Apache installing and configuring

Comment: I use Centos6.6.How I do?Please guide url!!

Comment: Google for centos apache installation manual. The process of configuring pretty same for all OSes